# How to use a class in other css file of CSS Modules?

Tags: reactjs, sass, css-modules

./index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import Child from '../Child/index';
import style from './index.scss';

const Parent = () => {
    return (
        <div className={style.parent}>
            <Child/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Parent;
```

./index.scss

```
.parent {
    // styles...
}
```

./Child/index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import style from './index.scss';

const Child = () => {
    return <div className={style.child}></div>;
}

export default Child;
```

./Child/index.scss

```
.child {
    // styles...
}
```

and I want to use `.parent:hover .child { //...style }` in scss files like

```
import '../index.scss';

.parent {
    &:hover {
        .child {
            // ...style
        }
    }
}

.child {
    // styles...
}
```

Is there any solution for this problem? I'm looking for relate information(like [issue](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules/issues/102)) but I have not found it yet.